# Message.entities выдает NoneType в Pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

Моя задача состоит в том чтобы обработать последние 20 сообщений в чате Телеграма (на клиентской стороне), и если они содержат ссылку или упоминание пользователя, то вывести в терминал ОК:

```
async for message in app.get_chat_history(target_username, limit=20):
    if type(message.entities) != None:
        for entitie in message.entities:
            if entitie.type == enums.MessageEntityType.URL or entitie.type == enums.MessageEntityType.MENTION:
                print('OK')
```

И при выполнении кода мне выдает следующую ошибку:

```
    for entitie in message.entities:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь сравнить имя класса `NoneType` с типом `None`.
Суть такая:

```py
var = None
print(var) # None
print(type(var)) # <class 'NoneType'>

# Неправильная проверка:
if type(var) != None: # <class 'NoneType'> != None
    print('ok') # Сработает

# Правильная проверка:
if var != None:
   print('ok') # Не сработает
```

В вашем же случае:

```py
async for message in app.get_chat_history(target_username, limit=20):
    if message.entities != None:
        for entitie in message.entities:
            if entitie.type == enums.MessageEntityType.URL or entitie.type == enums.MessageEntityType.MENTION:
                print('OK')
```

Comment: Еще лучше так `if message.entities is not None:`. Или упросить условие до `if message.entities`, тогда будет выполнять цикл если message.entities не None и не пустой список (или что там за объект).